# How can I enable an "Apps for Office" app to run on a mobile browser?

Tags: c#, ms-office, office365, apps-for-office

I've created an "Apps for Office" mail app that's working in both the Outlook 2013 desktop app and Office 365 on desktop browsers. However, when I use Office 365 on a mobile browser the "app bar" never loads and therefore there's no way to launch my app. I've taken a desktop browser where my mail app appeared, switched the user-agent to a mobile browser agent, and the app stops loading.

According to [Overview of apps for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220082.aspx):

> Apps can run in multiple environments, including Office desktop
> applications, Office Online in *both desktop and mobile browsers (my emphasis)*, and a
> growing number of Office tablet and phone apps.

What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn594603.aspx explains how to set up the manifest file for different versions of the app. I'll post that as an answer if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Set up a mail app for Outlook on desktops, tablets and mobile devices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn594603.aspx) explains what to do. Basically if you manually edit your manifest xml file you'll see a `<DesktopSettings>` element defined.

You can add additional `<TabletSettings>` and `<PhoneSettings>` elements to handle those cases, optionally providing entirely different pages for your app.